# Python lxml html xpath regex parsing

Tags: python, html, regex, xpath, lxml

I have an issue using regex in `lxml` `etree.XPath` expression in Python 3.6

In this example i'm searching for 4 digit number surrounded by white space, on the **stackoverflow** homepage. And returning the `xpath` of that element.

I'm getting match's that are just white space. I cant seem to be able to filter them out. My feelings are that it may be some encoding issue, but cant put my finger on it...

The picture below is from `https://regex101.com/`. Correctly giving me 1 match.

here is a link to the homepage html:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3HIB_5rVAxmZU9ialZHdzhscE0

[image]

**Here's my code**

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

with open('stackoverflow.html', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    page_html = f.read()

html_tree = html.fromstring(page_html)

regexpNS = "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
find = etree.XPath("//*[re:test(., '(\s\d{4}\s)', 'i')]",
                       namespaces={'re':regexpNS})

tree = etree.fromstring(page_html)
tree = etree.ElementTree(tree)
for element in find(tree):
    text = str(element.text)
    str(text).strip()
    if text != '':
        print(text)
        print(len(text))
        print(tree.getpath(element))
        print('##############################################################')
```

**Outputs**

```
    None
    4
    / *
    ##############################################################

    13
    / * / *[2]
    ##############################################################

    13
    / * / *[2] / * [8]
    ##############################################################

    17
    / * / *[2] / * [8] / *
    ##############################################################

    21
    / * / *[2] / * [8] / * / *
    ##############################################################

    25
    / * / *[2] / * [8] / * / * / * [18]
    ##############################################################

    29
    / * / *[2] / * [8] / * / * / * [18] / *
    ##############################################################

    33
    / * / *[2] / * [8] / * / * / * [18] / * / * [2]
    ##############################################################
    site
    design / logo © 2017
    Stack
    Exchange
    Inc;
    user
    contributions
    licensed
    under
    117
    / * / *[2] / * [8] / * / * / * [18] / * / * [2] / *
    ##############################################################
```

Whats up with the blank text lines with `len` > 0 that should have been stripped???

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... no one explained why I was getting multiple results for the xpath regex expression... A work around was good enough. The root question is different to the reason it is a duplicate. I suppose it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns a stripped text, but does not change `text`.

```
>>> text = '    a    '
>>> text.strip()   # returns a new string
'a'
>>> text  # `text` is not changed
'    a    '
```

---

If you want change `text`, you need to reassign the return value of the above expression back to `text` (BTW, you don't need to call `str(..)` because `text` is already a `str` object:

```
str(text).strip()
```

should be replaced with:

```
text = text.strip()
```

Comment: Arhh, a string is immutable? That's why? and yeah i saw that but  I was trying to Jam it into a type because it was being odd...

Comment: @JamesSchinner, Yes, strings are immutable in python.

Comment: Yes that solved my problem. I'm now able to filter out the blanks. So thanks! Though, I still don't know why i'm getting blank matches and even a `None` type.

Comment: @JamesSchinner, Because it's converted to string `'None'` (because of `str(element.text)`. You can filter that out just below the `for ...`: `if element.text is None: continue`

Comment: The None isn't a `None` it's a "None" - solved. Cheers mate!

Comment: @downvoter, Please let me know how to improve the answer.